# What SQL data type does Oracle assign to "count(*)"?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

What SQL data type does Oracle assign to `count(*)` in a query like `select count(*) from table`?  Does this depend on the count size?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The value is an integer; Oracle only has a `NUMBER` data type.

Comment: This leads to my next question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504521/what-java-data-type-corresponds-to-the-oracle-sql-data-type-numeric.

Comment: @Derek Mahar: Somehow, I knew that was the ultimate question... :)

Comment: @OMG: So you may get rep for two answers for the price of one ultimate question!

Comment: @Derek Mahar: Nah, I was close - it's been over a year since I worked with Java/Oracle, and I don't have my source handy to check.

Comment: @OMG, Just FYI, Oracle does have an INTEGER datatype. It's internally implemented as a NUMBER, but the type exists.

Comment: @DCookie: Thx, yeah - knew that Oracle subtypes the data types but they're all NUMBER ultimately.