# What object type does Spring Hibernate Template execute method return for a counting query on Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring, types

When run against and Oracle database, what is the runtime type of the object that the following [Spring Hibernate Template](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) (Spring 2.5 and Hibernate 3.3.2GA) code returns where the SQL query is a counting query like `select count(*) from table`?

```
 String sql = "select count(*) from table";
 BigDecimal count = (BigDecimal) hibernateTemplate.execute(
   new HibernateCallback() { 
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
     SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
     return (BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult();
    }});
 return count;
```

This code throws the following exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.put(StandardQueryCache.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.putResultInQueryCache(Loader.java:2185)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2087)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:804)
    at com.db.abstrack.dao.hibernate.RfqCdoUsDaoHibernate$1.doInHibernate(RfqCdoUsDaoHibernate.java:124)
```

Comment: Erm, run the code? If there is no ClassCastException, it was a BigDecimal, otherwise the exception will tell you what type it was. (HibernateTemplate.execute returns the object returned by the supplied HibernateCallback, which you cast to BigDecimal).

Comment: What version of hibernate library are you using? It used to return an Integer, but now it should be a Long.

Comment: Updated question to show Hibernate 3.3.2GA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that the `ClassCastException` may be due to a bug in the Hibernate standard query cache.

Solution is to add a scalar to the query:

```
String sql = "select count(*) as result from table";
BigDecimal count = (BigDecimal) ht.execute(new HibernateCallback() {
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
            throws HibernateException {
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        // Add scalar to avoid bug in Hibernate query cache.
        query.addScalar("result", Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL);
        return query.uniqueResult();
    }
});
```

References:

- [ClassCastException with SQLQuery and setCacheable(true)](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2391020)
- [Martin Schaaf's Blog: ClassCastException with SQLQuery and setCacheable(true)](http://infram.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/classcastexception-with-sqlquery-and-setcacheabletrue/)
- [Caching a raw sql count with Hibernate and EhCache](http://blog.pfa-labs.com/2009/12/caching-raw-sql-count-with-hibernate.html)
- [HHH-5163 Bug when applying a ResultTransformer on a cacheable projection based criteria](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-4175?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel)
- [ClassCastException when Hibernate tries to cache results using ResultTransformer](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2463)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for posting this (and +1 all around).

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. Unfortunately I can't use your solution, because my criteria query returns an entity (rather than just a scalar) using a `ResultTransformer`. According to the _HHH-5163_ bug description this should be fixed once Hibernate 4.0.0 is released

Answer (score 15):

How about

```
long value = ((Number)query.uniqueResult()).longValue();
return Long.valueOf(value);
```

This would work for all subclasses of Number like Long, Double, Biginteger or BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

I think it returns type Long. I have used Long in my code. But if your BigDecimal works then even I want to know what is the return type :)

Answer (score 0):

The class type of the object that `hibernateTemplate.execute()` returns is indeed `BigDecimal`.  It turns out that the cause of the `ClassCastException` is the cast of the return value of method `doInHibernate()`:

```
(BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult();
```

Corrected code:

```
 BigDecimal count = (BigDecimal) hibernateTemplate.execute(
   new HibernateCallback() { 
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
     SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
     return query.uniqueResult();
    }});
 return count;
```

Comment: This didn't solve the problem.  Apparently, there may be a bug in the Hibernate query cache.