# Datatype for the SELECT SUM call from java

Tags: java, oracle, select, jdbc

I am using Oracle database and making a SELECT SUM(mycolumn)....   call from my Java app. However, sometimes I get an incorrect sum. Executing the statement again returns  the correct sum.So it looks intermittent. Do I need to do resultSet.getDouble or something else. I am referring to this link which is hinting a datatype problem in the Aggregate function
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbvx/index.html

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(mycolumn) AS COUNT FROM .......")
long count=0;
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            count = resultSet.getLong("COUNT");
        }
```

Comment: sum() returns the same data type as the numeric data type of the argument.

Comment: Presume that your JDBC driver is latest one.

Comment: Does it help if you use `BigDecimal` instead of `Long`?

Comment: My DB Table column is of datatype NUMBER. What is appropriate to use in this case? I wish to use something that is correct and not based on my experiments. I want to avoid surprises later.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3504521/

Comment: The getObject returns BigDecimal. I will use a getBigDecimal. However, any idea why I am getting a wrong result even when the sum is as small as a 9 digit number, in my case ? This is not big and  should work even with  resultset.getInt? Shouldn't it ?

Comment: Please define "wrong result".  We are not telepathic, show us what you get and what you expect instead.